Why do scrolling styles not apply in my SolidJS and Tailwind component?
I am building a chat application with SolidJS and TailwindCSS. The chat messages are displayed in a container using Solids For component. Despite applying the appropriate tailwind classes, the chat window is not scrollable and no scrollbar appears.
<div class="flex flex-col justify-end box-border overflow-auto max-h-full grow basis-0 px-4 py-0 scroll-smooth">
  <For each={store.messages}>
    {({ message_id, message, prompt, sender, source }) => (
      <ChatMessage
        message_id={message_id}
        message={message}
        prompt={prompt}
        source={source}
        sender={sender}
      />
    )}
  </For>
</div>

When checking the element in the developer console in the browser, the style is applied but doesn't seem to take effect. According to the browser it's not being overwritten by another style. All over styles are working.
Is there anything I am missing here?
Even though I am applying overflow-auto and have set the height and max height of the parent container, a scrollbar never appears. If I explicitly set overflow: scroll, a greyed out scrollbar appears that is not usable.

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? Also please read how to ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.

I found the problem through a related question. When setting justify-end, it overrules the overflow behaviour. Instead, I set flex-col-reverse and then reversed the array. To always stay on the bottom, I implemented an effect that scrolls to the bottom whenever the message array changes:
let chatContainerRef: HTMLDivElement;

createEffect(() => {
  if (chatContainerRef) {
    chatContainerRef.scrollTop = chatContainerRef.scrollHeight;
  }
}, [store.messages.length]);

return (
  <div
    ref={(scrollContainer) => {
      chatContainerRef = scrollContainer;
    }}
    class="flex flex-col-reverse box-border overflow-auto max-h-full grow basis-0 px-4 py-0 scroll-smooth"
  >
    <For each={[...store.messages].reverse()}>
      {({ message_id, message, prompt, sender, source }) => (
        <ChatMessage
          message_id={message_id}
          message={message}
          prompt={prompt}
          source={source}
          sender={sender}
        />
      )}
    </For>
  </div>
);

